# Bulk INSERT without FIELDDELIMITER

Tags: sql-server

How can I bulk insert a file like below?

**test.txt**

```
012341231

013212313

011312321

012312312
```

The text file does not contain a delimiter. I have used:

```
 BULK INSERT tbl_import_#id#
    FROM '../test.txt'
    WITH 
        (FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
         ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

and I got an error for that. Appreciate any help thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem. You can specify a field terminator even if your file doesn't have any field terminators like `\t` or `,`.

Please try to post what error you have got. Check your `FROM` file ".../test.txt" location and table schema to import data. Better to post your error. I cannot reproduce your error. It works fine for me (I used your values).

Comment: btw, the table schema I use contain two columns that are id and number..I just want to insert the data into the number column.

Comment: Fine.. If you don't have delimiter why you create two columns?

Comment: Ah..I got it. Thanks. The table is the problem. :)

Comment: If you have delimiter you can change your table schema for the second column like "Col2 [nvarchar](100) default 'test'", then you can insert data without any problem... Otherwise Bulk Insert cannot find the termination of the line and you will get the same exception like you mentioned"

Answer (score 0):

Just run the query without `FILEDTERMINATOR`

```
 BULK INSERT tbl_import_#id#
    FROM '../test.txt'
    WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

The `FIELDTERMINATOR` argument would be helpful in case you had multiple columns in your table (more values per row). But I can see that this is not the case, so you don't need to separate values except by rows, which will be records in your table.

**EDIT:**

In case you can use a different table, just create a table with only 1 column(ID column) and run the import (the query above).

After that, run an `ALTER` command and add the other columns that you want.

Comment: I've run the query without Fieldterminator and another error is occured. The error stated that 'unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file'

Comment: @crystalix Do you have white lines, without text, between your rows? Can you try removing those? (at the end of the file also)

Comment: I removed all the white lines and the error is still the same.

Comment: @crystalix What version of SQL Server are you using? Also, what is the encoding of the file?

Comment: mssql server 2012..and btw, the table I used to insert the data contain two columns that are Id and number.. I just want to insert the data into the number column as the Id is auto inc.

Comment: @crystalix Is the table empty?

Comment: yap. The table is empty. I think the problem is with my table. It contains two column and the data I want to insert is only one column. Thanks for helping